# Lazy class attribute initialization

Tags: python, lazy-initialization

I have a class that takes only one input argument. This value will then be used to compute a number of attributes (only one in the following example). What is a pythonic way if I wanted to take the computation place only if I call the attribute. In addition, the result should be cached and `attr2` must not be set from outside the class.

```
class LazyInit:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.attr1 = val
        self.attr2 = self.compute_attr2()

    def compute_attr2(self):
        return self.attr1 * 2  # potentially costly computation


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = LazyInit(10)

    # actual computation should take place when calling the attribute
    print(obj.attr2)
```

Comment: Define a getter (*[`property` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `attr2` a property, not an instance attribute.

```
class LazyInit:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.attr1 = val
        self._attr2 = None

    @property
    def attr2(self):
        if self._attr2 is None:
            self._attr2 = self.compute_attr2()
        return self._attr2
```

`_attr2` is a private instance attribute that both indicates whether the value has been computed yet, and saves the computed value for future access.

Comment: In some cases it could be a good option to use [`cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) decorator.

Answer (score 4):

As hinted [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379177/lazy-class-attribute-initialization/69379447#comment122627346_69379239), just use `@cached_property` decorator.

```py
from functools import cached_property

class LazyInit():
    ...
    @cached_property
    def attr2(self):
        return <perform expensive computation>
```

[Olvin Roght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824407/olvin-roght) correctly [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379177/lazy-class-attribute-initialization/69379447#comment122628928_69379447) that this solution doesn't make `attr2` read-only the way that `@property` does. If that is important to you, another possibility would be to write:

```py
    ...
    @property
    def attr2(self):
        return self.__internal_attr2()

    @functools.cached
    def __internal_attr2(self):
        return <perform expensive calculation>
```

In any case, Python provides libraries to help you ensure that a value is only calculated once. It is better to use them than to try and write your own.

Comment: As I said in [*comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379177/lazy-class-attribute-initialization#comment122627346_69379239) under [*accepted answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69379239/10824407), it **could** be an option. Quote from docs: *"The mechanics of [`cached_property()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) are somewhat different from [`property()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)"*. If you need a property to be read-only or to define custom setter `cached_property` is not your choice.

Comment: This is definitely worth looking at! Thanks!

Comment: @OlvinRoght.  You are absolutely right.  I edited the solution above to deal with the case that the user wants read-only.

Comment: I was wondering that if the class attribute is different with instance property. What the answer solved is that the time-consuming __internal_attr2 is calculated once for each instance of LazyInit but not for all different instances of LazyInit.